# Disable Windows 8 sleep WITHOUT disabling screen turning off

Tags: windows-8, sleep

To run long-duration operations on my Windows 8 laptop, I need for it to not go to sleep. HOWEVER, I still want the screen to be able to automatically urn off after a time without keyboard presses and mouse movement. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is easy. I do this with all my machines.

Turn Sleep OFF and Hibernation OFF in Power Settings. Make sure the machine does not go to sleep.

Then set the monitor (Display) to go off in XX minutes - whatever you wish.

I do this routinely and it works well.